# Loading Listview when using WebView to scrape some data from the web

Tags: android, android-listview, android-webview, listactivity, android-asynctask

First, this is my source code

```
public void loadTheLoaiList() 
{
    Log.d("test", "Loading List");
    DataListView dlv = new DataListView(Main.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.id.lblTheLoai, wpc.getCat().getTheLoai());
    setListAdapter(dlv);
}

public void loadData()
{


    AsyncTask<String, String, String> loadDataFromWeb = new AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {
        private ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(Main.this);
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            pd.setTitle("Loading...");
            if(!pd.isShowing())
            {
                pd.show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

             wpc = new WOIMPageControl(Main.this);
             wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
             wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

             wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() 
             {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view,
                        String url) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }   
                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                    if(url.equalsIgnoreCase("http://www.abc.net/"))
                    {
                        Log.d("test", "URL matched !");
                        wv.loadUrl("javascript:$(document).ready(function() {" +
                                "WOIM.getTheLoai($('html').html());" +
                            "});");
                    }
                }    
             });
             wv.addJavascriptInterface(wpc, "WOIM");
             wv.loadUrl("http://www.abc.net/");
             return "";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(pd.isShowing())
            {
                pd.hide();
            }
            loadTheLoaiList();
        }   
    };
    loadDataFromWeb.execute("");
```

I'm using addJavascriptInterface to get the HTML and processing and then set the data to `ArrayList` and then fill it to the `ListView`.

But when I start the program, the `ListView` didn't receive the data.

I've figured out because the WebView just call the `loadUrl('http://abc.net')` method then jump directly to the `onPostExecute()` method without waiting the `WebView` to finished loading

That's why the `ListView`'s `ArrayList` doesn't have the data so the `ListView` didn't load.

I can't use Jsoup because Jsoup can't do ajax processing.

Answer (score 0):

all is happening as it should happen.
When you started the webView's loading, its a different thread and hence it just starts and the control moves to the "onPostExecute()".
If you want to do something (populating lis) after the page loading finishes, you must add that code to the "onPageFinished()" method of the webView. 
It is the method (callback) provided for this purpose and the name also suggests that.

Comment: You mean placing the loadTheLoaiList(); in the onPageFinished() ? I have already done that, but it won't works because this method always run before the javascript interface done processing!